# Ada Makefile Binding Issue

Tags: makefile, ada, gnat

I am working on a project in Ada and would like a custom makefile (as I intend to interface with c and python eventually and am very familiar with makefile syntax and not at all familiar with gnatmake project syntax). I messed around with custom compilation and thought I had it working, but my makefile which at least looks like it does the exact same command-line execution runs into problems at the binding stage.

I figure I probably am having an off-by-one directory error, or am over/under complicating something.

Anyways, my project currently contains 3 source directories (but more are coming). Model contains the 'logic', util contains common utilities, and test contains un-packaged 'main' procedures. Eventually I'll also have some 'main' procedures out in my src directory. ASCII Picture:

```
project
  \- bin
      \- test
           \- ....out
      \- other_dirs_coming_soon
           \- ....out
      \- ....out
  \- obj
      \- all the mess that ada compilation makes
      \- including .o, .ali, and b~whatever.ad(b/s)
  \- src
      \- model
           \- ....ad(b/s)
      \- util
           \- ....ad(b/s)
      \- ...
```

I tried a 'basic' makefile which was very close to what I wanted:

```
.PHONY: clean test

MAKE=gnatmake
INCLUDE_DIRS=-Imodel -Iutil -Itest
GNATMAKEFLAGS=-g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --GNATLINK="gnatlink -v" --GNATBIND="gnatbind -v"
GCCFLAGS=-g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
OBJDIR=../obj
BINDFLAGS=-a0$(OBJDIR) 

PLAYER_TEST_EXE=../bin/player_test.out

test : $(PLAYER_TEST_EXE)

$(PLAYER_TEST_EXE) : test/player_test.adb
    gnatmake $< -D $(OBJDIR) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -o $@ $(GNATMAKEFLAGS)

clean : 
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/* $(PLAYER_TEST_EXE) b~*
```

The problem is that this creates those `b~*` files in the working directory whenever a debug flag is passed. As I intend to have many many executables, this will significantly pollute my working directory.

As such I peeled open the makefile step-by-step and ended up with:

```
.PHONY: clean test

GCC=gcc
BINDER=gnatbind

ADALIBLOC=`gnatls -v | grep adalib`

FLAGS=
LINKFLAGS=-gnatA -gnatWb -gnatiw -gnatws

test: FLAGS+=-g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
test: LINKFLAGS+=-g

# Where to put the object files and ali extensions
OBJDIR=../obj

# Source directories
MODEL_DIR=model
UTIL_DIR=util
TEST_DIR=test

SRC_DIRS=$(MODEL_DIR) $(UTIL_DIR) $(TEST_DIR)
INC_DIRS=${SRC_DIRS:%=-I%}
LIB_DIRS=${SRC_DIRS:%=-L%}
BIND_DIRS=${SRC_DIRS:%=-aO./%}

# Model sources
MODEL_SPECS=$(wildcard $(MODEL_DIR)/*.ads)
MODEL_BODIES=$(wildcard $(MODEL_DIR)/*.adb)
MODEL_OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.ads,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(MODEL_SPECS))
MODEL_ALI=$(patsubst %.ads,$(OBJDIR)/%.ali,$(MODEL_SPECS))

# Util sources
UTIL_SPECS=$(wildcard $(UTIL_DIR)/*.ads)
UTIL_BODIES=$(wildcard $(UTIL_DIR)/*.adb)
UTIL_OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.ads,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(UTIL_SPECS))
UTIL_ALI=$(patsubst %.ads,$(OBJDIR)/%.ali,$(UTIL_SPECS))

# All sources
ALL_SPECS=$(MODEL_SPECS) $(UTIL_SPECS)
ALL_BODIES=$(MODEL_BODIES) $(UTIL_BODIES)
ALL_OBJECTS=$(MODEL_OBJECTS) $(UTIL_OBJECTS)
ALL_ALIS=$(MODEL_ALI) $(UTIL_ALI)

# Executables
EXE_DIR=../bin
PLAYER_TEST_EXE=$(EXE_DIR)/test/player_test.out

# Targets
test : $(PLAYER_TEST_EXE)

# Executable creation
$(EXE_DIR)/%.out : $(EXE_DIR)/%.o $(ALL_OBJECTS)
    cd $(EXE_DIR)
    $(GCC) $*.o $(ALL_OBJECTS) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $(LIB_DIRS) -L$(ADALIBLOC)/libgnat.a --static-libgcc

# Executable object creation
$(EXE_DIR)/%.o : $(EXE_DIR)/%.adb
    cd $(OBJBINDIR)
    $(GCC) -c $(FLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) $< -o $@

# Executable source creation
$(EXE_DIR)/%.adb : $(OBJDIR)/%.ali $(ALL_OBJECTS)
    cd $(EXE_DIR)
    $(BINDER) $(BIND_DIRS) $(INC_DIRS) -v -x ../$< -o ../$*.adb

# Object creation
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.adb %.ads
$(OBJDIR)/%.o :
    if [ -a $*.adb ]; then \
        gcc -c $*.adb $(INC_DIRS) -o $@ $(FLAGS); \
    else \
        gcc -c $*.ads $(INC_DIRS) -o $@ $(FLAGS); \
    fi;

# ALI creation
$(OBJDIR)/%.ali : %.adb %.ads
$(OBJDIR)/%.ali :
    if [ -a $*.adb ]; then \
        gcc -c $*.adb $(INC_DIRS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$*.o $(FLAGS); \
    else \
        gcc -c $*.ads $(INC_DIRS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$*.o $(FLAGS); \
    fi;

clean:
    @rm -f $(ALL_OBJECTS) $(ALL_ALI)
```

Which seems to be really close, except it can't find player_test.ali when it gets to the binding stage.

Any advice?

Comment: Doing it this way, you’re never going to get the dependencies right. gnatmake used to support -M to output dependencies in a Makefile form, but no more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you reconsider your decision to solve the problem completely without project files.  I typically use a combination of project files and a makefile for building Ada projects with GNAT.

You would need a GNAT project file per object directory, as a project file only can point to a single object directory.

If you have common compiler flags for most of the project, it makes sense to have them in a common project file, which the other project files are derived from.

Comment: Ok, I thought it may be an issue outside the scope of what make could do. Time to research how to use GNAT project files! 
Thank you for the dose of reality.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Using GNAT projects is the ideal solution. Nonetheless:

I found GNAT projects as a system very cumbersome, especially since gprbuild is not yet a standard package for my system, and gnatmake has depracated the `-P` flag. As such, I created an in-between solution.

I created a new directory `build` alongside my `src` directory. Inside `build` I symlinked all of my source directories. I then added this Makefile within build:

```
.PHONY: clean test
.SILENT:

FLAGS=-d
GNATLINKFLAGS=
GNATBINDFLAGS=

test: FLAGS+=-g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

MAKE=gnatmake
INCLUDE_DIRS=-Imodel -Iutil -Itest
GNATLINK=--GNATLINK="gnatlink $(GNATLINKFLAGS)"
GNATBIND=--GNATBIND="gnatbind $(GNATBINDFLAGS)"
GNATMAKEFLAGS=$(FLAGS) $(GNATLINK) $(GNATBIND)

OBJDIR=../obj
SRCDIR=../src

# Executable definitions
PLAYER_TEST_SRC=test/player_test.adb
PLAYER_TEST_EXE=../bin/player_test.out

test : $(PLAYER_TEST_EXE)

$(PLAYER_TEST_EXE) : force_make
    gnatmake $(PLAYER_TEST_SRC) -D $(OBJDIR) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -o $@ $(GNATMAKEFLAGS)

force_make:
    true

clean : 
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*
```

Then I created this very minimal Makefile within src:

```
.SILENT:
BUILD_DIR=../build

% : force_make
    cd $(BUILD_DIR); make $@

force_make:
    true
```

Now I can run `make test` from within my source directory and it will create my test executable as expected.

The benefit of this system is that as I learn about project files I can easily add them to the build directory so as to allow an incremental transition from a pure GNU make solution to a pure GNAT project solution.